# A skeleton in the cupboard/ closet

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Is there an equivalent phrase in Latin that readily springs to mind of any colleague, meaning ‘a shameful secret known only to family members’? I know you could say res turpis intra familiam condita or the like but this would be merely a translation. An academic friend suggested (with a fortuitous echo of words in scelus—-sceletus) the iambic ‘velavit ultro turpe conditum scelus’ for ‘he unwittingly revealed the skeleton in his cupboard’. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I would think that *velavit* would mean "cover" and not "uncover".

Comment: Thanks, Figulus! Of course you are correct. To keep the metre I suggest ‘nudavit’.